# How can I make my MainWindow.fxml print the earlier entries in a list?

Tags: java, list, javafx

I am trying to make my first javaFx window show the results of a Questionnaire for CS bachelor, it prints the correct username and score, I however also have a place where I want to print the other entries to that list (in the programs lifetime).
Any help would be appreciated, if there is any code that feels like its missing do say so as I am very new at programming

I tried doing this with the following code in the Controller class that sends me to the MainWindow again

```
    public void clickMainMenuBtn(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/MainWindow.fxml"));
        Parent mainSceneRoot = loader.load();
        MainController mainController = loader.getController();
        UserScore userScore = new UserScore(SecondController.getUserNameInput(), ScoreCalculated);

        mainController.initialize(userScore);
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) Score.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.setScene(new Scene(mainSceneRoot));
```

and here is the intialize code that is getting run in the code above :

```
public void initialize(UserScore userScore)
    {
        userNameLabel.setText(userScore.getUserName());
        scoreLabel.setText(String.valueOf(userScore.getScore()));

        NameAndScoreList.add(userScore);

        displayNameAndScoreList();
    }
```

and here is the last method called in the initialize method

```
   public void displayNameAndScoreList()
    {
        StringBuilder NameAndScoreListText = new StringBuilder("Tidligere Score:\n");

        for(UserScore userScore : NameAndScoreList)
        {
            NameAndScoreListText.append(userScore.getUserName()).append(": ").append(userScore.getScore()).append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(NameAndScoreListText.toString());
        EarlierScores.setText(NameAndScoreListText.toString());

    }
```

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _I tried doing this with the following code_ If possible, I would prefer if you [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. I also suggest that you take the [tour] and visit the [help]. In any case, I don't understand what your problem is. Maybe you can post a screen capture of your JavaFX application and indicate where the problem is.

Comment: You need an appropriate place to store the list of scores; the usual way to do this is to create a model class to store application data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx

Comment: Off-topic: It is better to use a `ListView` to display a list of objects than to use a `TextArea`.

Comment: To display a table of names and scores, you might consider a [`TableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm).  An example of [using a TableView from FXML](https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/part2/), if you choose to use FXML as part of your solution.